# How to access Hadoop remotely?

Tags: openstack, hadoop

I have installed Hadoop on open-stack CentOS guest VM. I'm able to open the site:

```
(From 192.168.0.10, VM-1)
http://localhost:50070
http://192.168.0.10:50070
```

But not able to access the same from a remote machine (My Computer).

```
http://210.84.35.1:50070
```

Here is my network diagram:

```
                                                          Open-Stack
                               ---------------------------------------------------------------                                
                               |                                                             |
                               |   [Remote Network]          [Open-Stack-VM Network]         |
                               |                                                             |
                               |                   |           |192.168.0.10                 | 
                               |  210.84.35.0/24   |           |____________ [CentOS VM-1]   | 
[My-Computer] ----(Internet)---|--- _______________|___________|                             | 
                               |                   |           |192.168.0.11                 | 
                               |                   |           |____________ [CentOS VM-2]   |
                               |-------------------|-----------|-----------------------------
```

Comment: You must create a port redirect rule on your VM program.

Comment: There is no port redirect for ssh? How i am able to do that. Can you please tell me the steps?

Comment: If you can access 192.168.0.10 via ssh, you can use `ssh -L 9999:127.0.0.1:50070 user@192.168.0.10` on MyComputer first, and connect to `http://MyComputer:9999/`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Openstack provides the option for assigning Floating IPs. That's one of the options to enable you to access remotely.